# EntitySqlException: The command parameter syntax '@0' is not valid

Tags: dynamic-linq

I'm getting this error when I issue this:

```
DataContext.DBProjectEntities.Projects.Where(xWhere, parameterList.ToArray)
```

> The command parameter syntax '@0' is not valid. Near line 6, column 37.

- `xWhere` is a string containing value `"(ProjectStatuses.Any(DepartmentID = @0))"`
- `parameterList` is `Dim parameterList As New List(Of ObjectParameter)`

It contains one element with value 1 of type Int32 which corresponds to the type of DepartmentID.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. I was using the dunamic.vb from an external assembly. In my code I had imports statement for that assembly, but I also needed the imports for system.linq.dynamic